# VB how to get the return value after printing PDF file

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I know most of the people are using Adobe Reader/Acrobat to print a PDF file e.g.

```
startInfo.Verb = "Print"
startInfo.Arguments = " " & Printer.PrinterSettings.PrinterName & " "
startInfo.FileName = "file.pdf"

Process.Start(startInfo)
```

My question is that after program sends the PDF file to printer then its job is over so we don't know if the PDF file has been actually printed out correctly or not from the printer because it doesn't get any return value or log after that (e.g. it doesn't know if the PDF file job is stuck in the printer queue).

Is there a way to get any return value or information after sending the PDF file to printer and confirming the paper has been printed out?

Comment: Take a look at `System.Printing` namespace.  From there you should be able to monitor the print jobs.

Comment: [PrintQueueWatch - GitHub](https://github.com/MerrionComputing/PrintQueueWatch) -- [Monitoring a Printer Queue from VB.NET - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3313/Monitoring-a-Printer-Queue-from-VB-NET) -- [WMI - Win32_PrintJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printjob)

Comment: Take a look at [this - check printer spool](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58dc6f96-d517-4f0c-a964-4e83964ca68d/how-to-check-printer-spool?forum=Vsexpressvb)